# Que esta Mal en mi codigo, si me compila perfectamente (c++)

Tags: c++, struct, caracteres

estoy programando en c++ ejercicios para practicar, pero me tope con un problema y la verdad no es un problema de logica de programacion, sino mas bien es algo que no entiendo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct atletas
{
    char name[70];
    char pais[100];
    char disciplina[60];
    int medallas;
};

int main()
{
    atletas datoz[20];
    int n, mayor= 0;
    char country[100];
    cout<<"\n\tPROGRAMA PARA DATATECH"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEscriba el total de atletas: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el nombre: ";
        cin>>datoz[i].name;
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el pais de procedencia: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,datoz[i].pais);
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite la disciplina: ";
        cin.getline(datoz[i].disciplina,60,'\n');
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el Numeros de medallas: ";
        cin>>datoz[i].medallas;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre de un pais: ";
    cin.getline(country,100,'\n');
    cout<<"Atletas que provienen de "<<country;
    
    return 0;
}
```

El principal problema radica cuando intento ingresar palabras (caracteres)

```
cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el nombre: ";
        cin>>datoz[i].name;
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el pais de procedencia: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,datoz[i].pais);
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite la disciplina: ";
        cin.getline(datoz[i].disciplina,60,'\n');
        cout<<"#"<<i+1<<". Digite el Numeros de medallas: ";
        cin>>datoz[i].medallas;
        cout<<endl;
```

Intente hacerlo con cin.getline.... pero me pasa esto

[image: Lo que pasa]

"cin" propiamente no es bueno para introducir caracteres

"getline(cin,xxxxxx)" simplemente no me compila, me sale error
[image: Imagen que sale error con getline(cin,xxxxxx)]

Y mi ultimo problema es que, tengo declarado un array

```
 char country[100];
 cout<<"\nIngrese el nombre de un pais: ";
 cin.getline(country,100,'\n');
 cout<<"Atletas que provienen de "<<country;
```

Y me sucede esto...
[image: Error al imprimir]

Mi codigo todavia falta pulir, pero en esencia esos son los problemas que no entiendo porque suceden
No entiendo porque no me deja poner caracteres de manera correcta y si todo esta bien y suceden conflictos, quiero colocar caracteres para despues hacer una comparacion de estos por la funcion strcmp, pero si no me permite meter caracteres correctamenete , no podre hacer la comparacion
[image: Foto del Ejercicio]

[image: IMAGEN DE TODO MI CODIGO]

Comment: '*"getline(cin,xxxxxx)" simplemente no me compila, me sale error*'. Tienes que incluir `<string>`, sin el `.h` al final.

Comment: En C++ te interesa usar el header [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) (lo que te dijo Pablo) y reemplazar los arreglos de caracteres (`char[]`) por la clase `string`. Por otro, es probable que al leer un número estés dejando un salto de línea que debes descartar con `cin.ignore()`. Este último es un problema frecuente y ya hay respuestas al respecto.

Comment: Si usaria la clase string, pero el ejercicio que quiero resolver me pide comparar las cadenas y esto solo se puede hacer con strcmp, amenos que alguien sepa hacerlo con string

Comment: @DiegoGuti lo que dices no es cierto. `strcmp` es una funciónde [tag:c] (no [tag:c++]) que compara formaciones de caracteres (no cadenas), en C++ puedes comparar dos `std::string` con los operadores y funciones integrados en el objeto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Hola, me podrias dar un ejemplo o un prototipo de como hacer lo que me comentas.

Comment: @DiegoGuti `std::string a = "A"; std::string B = "Patatas fritas"; if (A == B) std::cout << "Esto se imprime si A y B son iguales\n";`

Comment: @Pablochaches Hize eso, pero el problema persiste, me sale esto 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t69lx.png

Comment: No me fije que estabas usando `char[]` en lugar de `std::string`. Lo correcto seria que usaras los strings de C++ en vez de arrays de caracteres. Pero si tu profesor no les permite usarlos, puedes usar `std::cin.getline(datoz[i].pais, 100)` ([documentacion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)). @DiegoGuti

Comment: Las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta. Los comentarios son sólo para que los que intentan responder pregunten cosas que no son evidentes en la pregunta o pidan aclaraciones. Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir todo lo que necesites aclarar

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar string.h usa string. En las partes que quieras capturar un valor con más de un carácter, guárdalo en una variable string en ves de char[]. Para guardar strings en C++ puedes usar getline(cin, tuVariableTipoString).